# transform dataframe with appropriate index

Tags: python, pandas

hi i have a dataframe that looks like that:

```
    0             1                2
0   A      A    A
1   26,2%   17,2%   12,5%
2   B          B    B
3   -          -    -
4   C          C    C
5   10,7%      -    -
6   D          D   D
7   -          -    -
8   E          E   E
9   -          -    -
10  F         F   F
11  12,6%   24,4%   27,7%
...
```

I would like to transform it to:

```
    col1    col2    col3
A   26,2%   17,2%   12,5%
B   -        -       -
C   10,7%   -        -
D   -         -     -
E   -          -    -
F   12,6%   24,4%   27,7%
...
```

How should I do it ?

Comment: Select only the odd rows, then reset the index to the even rows from the first column, and save it to s new df.

Answer (score 0):

If need set index by values in first column starting by `A-Z` use [`Series.str.match`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) for mask with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by same column with forward filling matched values with filter out matched rows:

```
m = df.iloc[:, 0].str.match(r'[A-Z]')
out = (df.set_index(df.iloc[:, 0].where(m).ffill())[~m.to_numpy()]
       .set_axis([f'col{x+1}' for x in df.columns], axis=1)
       .rename_axis(None))
```

Or if need match odd rows and set indices by even use:

```
out = (df.set_index(df.iloc[:, 0].shift()).iloc[1::2]
       .set_axis([f'col{x+1}' for x in df.columns], axis=1)
       .rename_axis(None))
print (out)
    col1   col2   col3
A  26,2%  17,2%  12,5%
B      -      -      -
C  10,7%      -      -
D      -      -      -
E      -      -      -
F  12,6%  24,4%  27,7%
```